# Is casting necessary in Typescript for this simple case?

Tags: casting, typescript

Say I have a test.ts and a MY_MODULE.d.ts file:

**MY_MODULE.d.ts:**

```
module MY_MODULE 
{
    export class Config { 
        UserId : string;
    };

    export function Init( config : Config );
}
```

**test.ts:**

```
/// <reference path="MY_MODULE.d.ts" />

MY_MODULE.Init(<MY_MODULE.Config>{ UserId: 'Josh' });
```

My question:  Is it possible to fix either the definition file or the .ts file so that the cast in the latter is unnecessary?

Comment: TypeScript is not JavaScript. I see no reason to tag a simple TypeScript question as JavaScript.

Comment: Nitpicking but I'd mention its actually type assertion (not casting).

Comment: The documentation does not call this casting. However this blog post just did : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/03/25/working-on-typescript-0-9-generics-overload-on-constants-and-compiler-performance.aspx quote: "In TypeScript 0.8, the code above would have required an additional cast though"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `export interface Config` instead of `export class Config`.

Comment: Can't you actually even omit the `export` inside a `*.d.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

Typescript will infer the correct type based on the signature of the object, so the cast is not necessary.
Copying the code into the playground, a couple of compile errors were immediately picked up.  Firstly, Init needs an implementation.
Secondly, the Config class does not have a constructor.
The following code compiles cleanly:

```
module MY_MODULE 
{
    export class Config { 
        UserId : string;
    };

    export function Init( config : Config ) {
    }
}

var myConfig = new MY_MODULE.Config();
myConfig.UserId = 'Josh'

MY_MODULE.Init(myConfig);
```

It would be better to define a constructor for Config as follows:

```
module MY_MODULE 
{
    export class Config {
        UserId : string; 
        constructor(userId : string) {
            this.UserId = userId;
        }
    };
    export function Init( config : Config ) {
    }
}

MY_MODULE.Init(new MY_MODULE.Config('Josh'));
```

Comment: MY_MODULE is a in a .d.ts file. There's no implementation there.